# How can I make multiple Path elements inside a Canvas scale to fit its parent?

Tags: c#, windows, canvas, path, windows-store-apps

I have created a series of shapes in Illustrator, and exported them to an .ai file. When I import this file in Blend for Visual Studio, I get something that looks like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="ManyPaths" Grid.Row="0">
    <Path Data="F1M0,53.135L0.004,102.44 22.03,151.59 55.042,0z" Fill="#FF8B1A34" Height="151.59" Canvas.Left="0.017" Stretch="None" Canvas.Top="182.406" Width="55.042"/>
    <Path Data="F1M0.003,34.152L22.027,49.15 0,0z" Fill="#FF991937" Height="49.15" Canvas.Left="0.02" Stretch="None" Canvas.Top="284.846" Width="22.027"/>
</Canvas>
```

There are numerous Paths, I won't list them all here for brevity. When put together, they make a fixed size rectangle. I would like to use this rectangle at the top of my app as the header image. I can resize the Canvas element in Blend, but I cannot get the collective Paths to fit the Canvas, and be resized along with it. Since I'm designing for various size screens, I would like the header image to scale. I have tried nesting it in a Grid, but that doesn't work.

Looks like the traditional way to do Paths in C# is

```
    <Path Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Green">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100">
                        <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="165,25" Point2="225,100" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

I'm not sure if there is a means to convert the first format to the second, but I would like to reuse my .ai files if possible, instead of recreating them from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to convert to the second format. Using the Data attribute is more concise and often clearer.

You can wrap your Canvas in a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox.aspx) to let it scale to its container. The Stretch attribute can control if it stretches uniformly or distorts (you probably want uniform)

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid x:Name="ManyPaths" >
        <Path Data="F1M0,53.135L0.004,102.44 22.03,151.59 55.042,0z" Fill="#FF8B1A34" Height="151.59" Canvas.Left="0.017" Stretch="None" Canvas.Top="182.406" Width="55.042"/>
        <Path Data="F1M0.003,34.152L22.027,49.15 0,0z" Fill="#FF991937" Height="49.15" Canvas.Left="0.02" Stretch="None" Canvas.Top="284.846" Width="22.027"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```